# Bruteforce with threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, brute-force

So I decided to make a bruteforce and it runs on in a loop. Its sadly really slow so here is the code and the problem:

```
import itertools
from time import sleep
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
from threading import Thread
import keyboard

count = CharLength = 1

pw = input("Password: ")

chars = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_.")

for CharLength in range(25):
    password = (itertools.product(chars, repeat = CharLength))
    for i in password:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
            print("\"esc\" pressed. Program ended.")
            exit()
        count += 1
        i = str(i)
        i = i.replace("'", "")
        i = i.replace(" ", "")
        i = i.replace(",", "")
        i = i.replace("(", "")
        i = i.replace(")", "")
        print(i)
        if i == pw:
            print("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=\n")
            print("Password found: " + i)
            print("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=\n")
            exit()
```

I wondered if I can speed the process of guessing passwords, maybe with multiple threads (can be without threads too ofc!)?

If there are any questions just ask me!

-Lotus

Comment: You could change `i = str(i)` to `i = ''.join(i)` and get rid of all those `i = i.replace(...)` lines.

Comment: You might be able to improve performance by using `re.sub()` to replace all the characters at once. As an aside, names like `i` for loop variables are generally used when the values are numeric, especially indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About Python and multithreading for optimisation:**

Please note, that Python uses the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)
In other words. Python will never execute more than one Python byte code at the same time even if you have multiple threads and multiple CPUs.

So for pure Python code (without C bindings, that release the GIL) Python threading will never increase the performance of CPU bound code)

If you want to increase performance I suggest, that you use the multiprocessing module instead.

**About potential optimisations:**

I tried to guess the password `awdf` on my over 10 years old machine:

With your code it needs about 18.5 seconds:

1.) Remove the print()
you're down to 11.3 seconds

2.) calling the function `keyboard.is_pressed()` is not cheap, so just check it only every 1000 times
You're down to 1.3 seconds

you do this with:

```
            if count % 1000 == 0:
                if keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
                    print("\"esc\" pressed. Program ended.")
                    exit()
```

3.) simpler way to convert result of itertools.product to a password

Instead of

```
            i = str(i)
            i = i.replace("'", "")
            i = i.replace(" ", "")
            i = i.replace(",", "")
            i = i.replace("(", "")
            i = i.replace(")", "")
```

just do

```
i ="".join(i)
```

your down to 0.2 seconds

4.) Instead of converting each result of itertools.product (a tuple) into a string
I can convert the password string outside of the loop once into a tuple, so I compare the tuples and don't convert.

I'm down to 0.15s

Fastest version is with 0.06s following.

No more counting / no more interrupting with `esc` (had to be done by killing the process)

```
    chars = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_.")

    pw = tuple(pw)

    for CharLength in range(1, 25):
        passwords = (itertools.product(chars, repeat = CharLength))

        first_match = filter(lambda elm: elm == pw, passwords)
        try:
            passwd = next(first_match)
            passwd =  "".join(passwd)
            print("Password found: " + passwd)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

But please be aware, that in most real case scenarios finding out whether a password is correct is not done by a string comparison, but by calculating a hash. These operations are intentionally slow, so they will probably be much more important than any of my optimisations here.